# Understanding Spec sheet of IC

Tags: current, integrated-circuit

I'm having trouble understanding the spec sheet of [this](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A240/SN74194_74LS194%23TEX.pdf) shift register. What I want to do is to connect a (generic red one, I don't have any specs) LED which will approximately use 15-35 mA to the IC.

I am currently doing this as seen in the first scheme. The output pins of the IC (\$Q_a\$ to \$Q_d\$) are each connected to NPN transistors, which then are each connected to LEDs.
The LEDs share a common resistor (850 Ohm). The power supply delivers 5V. I added the the transistors because the spec sheet states (page 6) the maximal "High-level output current" is -0.8 mA (and it states no minimal current). Since the LEDs need more than that, I added the transistors to augment the current.

My question is how to interpret the sign in -0.8 mA. Does this mean that I can push into the IC at most 0.8mA while its output is high (and that I can let out as much as I want), or does this mean that 0.8 mA is the most the IC can let out of this pin?

Am I correct that I could simplify my schematic into the second one (removing the transistors), should the first theory be right?

[image: Current configuration]

[image: Questionable configuration]

Comment: First off, you're driving your LEDs wrong. NPN transistors being used as switches should *always* (unless you know what you're doing) be on the low side, never the high side.

Comment: The shift register symbol is strange. It resembles a switch. Also no clock input.

Comment: Yes the symbol is a switch. I am new to electronics, so I improvised a bit when I didn't find any symbol for the actual IC. All other pins (Vcc, Gnd etc.) are missing in my schematic

Comment: @Hearth can you elaborate what this means? I don't know what the low/high side refers to

Comment: You should use a resistor for EACH LED.  When using a single resistor as you show, the LED current, and therefore brightness, will vary depending on the number of LEDs turned on.

Comment: What I mean is that the transistors should have the emitter (the terminal where the arrow is in the symbol) connected directly to the negative terminal of the power supply. The load being switched should always be on the collector of the transistor.

Comment: @Peter Bennet Yes that makes sense, thanks

Comment: Re, "The LEDs share a common resistor..." That's not a great idea if you plan to illuminate more than one of them at the same time because (a) what Peter Bennett said, above; and (b) The LEDs won't be equally bright when more than one of them is illuminated. The reason for (b) is, the I-V curve is very steep in the LED's normal operating range, and small manufacturing variations will prevent parallel LEDs from dividing the current equally.

Comment: Also, if you're going to keep working with TTL chips in the future, then you should pay attention to Tim Wescott's answer. TTL outputs can "sink" much more current than they can "source." It was common practice, back in TTL days, to treat outputs as "active low." You'd connect the LED or coil or whatever between the output pin and Vcc, and you'd set the output to "0" to turn the thing on or, to "1" to turn it off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a datasheet specifies a current in that way it doesn't mean that is the maximum the chip capability. It means that is the test condition.

The negative sign does indicate the current flow direction. Minus means current flow out of the chip.

A standard TTL input as defined about 50 years ago required a worst case sinking current of 1.6mA and a sourcing current of 40uA. Typically outputs were designed to be able to drive 10 of those giving a test condition of 16mA for the output low condition and 400uA for output high at 2.4V. Some devices were designed for a larger drive output such as 20. Since the 70's the required current to drive a logic input has reduced greatly; first with low power bipolar devices to a few hundred microamps and then with CMOS to sub microamp levels. Even though the DC current needed is very low the capacitance of wiring and gate inputs can still require significant drive capability.

I would not recommending designing a circuit with such an old device. There are more modern equivalents such as the [CD74HC194](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc194.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1651363308391&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fcd74hc194) or even directly from microcontroller outputs.

With your circuit description you don't need to drive 15-35mA anyway. With an 850 ohm (why 850 Ohm? that is non-standard) resistor to the 5V supply the current will only be about 3-4mA. That will illuminate a modern LED brightly. Normally I would use a 1k resistor for that application and drive directly from an MCU.

Also having a shared resistor implies that only one LED at a time is lit - is that what you want? A separate resistor for each will allow the LEDs to be controled individually. The shift register already allows independent control of the LEDs.

Lastly, unless there is a reason it is more common to connect the LED with resistor to the supply rail and use the logic device to drive its output low to illuminate the LED. Partly this is convention from when ICs could drive low more powerfully than they could drive high.

With separate resistors per LED it doesn't matter if the resistor or the LED connects to the supply. It may be more convenient to connect the LEDs to the supply as it allows a single wire to connect the LEDs back to the supply with separate wires for the other ends, 5 wires in total. If you connect the resistors to the supply you would need 8 wires. This is useful if the LEDs are mounted on a panel and not on the circuit board.

Comment: Yeah I think I will use negative logic to do this with this circuit

Answer (score 2):

The data sheet specifies an output high voltage (probably around 2.4V, because it's a 74LS series).  The current given as the current *into* the chip: a rating of -0.8mA means that the chip can only *deliver* 0.8mA when it is coming *out* of the chip.

Generally you don't want to "cheat" the specifications -- don't depend on a voltage output to deliver a current (meaning, you need to put a current-limit resistor in there), and don't assume that you can exceed the chip's ratings and have it live (meaning, you *may* be able to connect LEDs directly, and they *may* light up, but the chip may die, too).

Note that 74LS parts can sink way more current than they can source.  You can pull the output *down* to around 0.7V while sinking 8mA.  An old-style LED such as the hobbyist sources still sell will still glow visibly with this much current; if you go shopping for a new high-efficiency one, it'll shine in full sun at that current.

So if you run even a hobbyist LED from the positive rail, through a 390 ohm resistor, then to the chip pin, it should work sorta-kinda OK, with no transistors, at the cost of the sense being inverted.

Note that 74LS series parts are pretty much obsolete -- a 74HC part will handle more current (= more brightness), and it will source and sink the same current.

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign in front just means the direction of current.

In this case it means the chip can source (push out) 0.8mA maximum from output pin.

Without minus sign, it means the chip can sink (pull in) current.

Answer (score 1):

Old school TTL was designed to switch with higher current with low logic "0"  levels (e.g. 16 mA max ) and similarly needed more current for low-level input.  Thus true to each TTL family they had a current ratio of >=10 for high speed which was called a fan-out of 10 loads from each output.  (in this case \$I_{IL} = 1\$ mA)

Thus it would be better to choose <=15 mA for the LED and use more efficient LEDs. Some are very bright even at 3 mA, while old ones are dim at 20 mA.

Thus for a Red 2.1V from 5V with a Vol = 0.2V typ output. the series R=V/I= (5-2.1-0.2)/15 mA = 2.7/15 mA = 0.18 kohm.(min)

True to all electronic conventions, the negative current comes from V+ and power supplies are negative power and loads consume positive power to satisfy polarity rules.

**The active-low input needs more current so the drivers can supply this but are limited on the high side.**

**The concept of fan-out was limited to TTL, but often schematics look more like orthogonal spread-out loads than radial fans.**
[image]

### Conclusion:

**Use negative logic to drive loads from TTL (54/74 series)**

[image]

Comment: But then don't you want to connect the LED's such that the anode & resistor go to +5V, and the output of the shift register connects to the cathode of the LEDs?  That would be consistent with your analysis, the IC being to sink 15 mA.

Comment: @SteveSh  That's correct, you use inverted or "negative" logic, which was  common for TTL, so low  means "active"  with LED ON at 0.2V output and Common Anodes to V+. That's how the 1st TTL digital watch worked with LED's.  Then CMOS was more symmetrical but still slightly better on the Nch side so CMOS started using "Positive Logic"

Comment: I understand that.  But I'm not sure OP would.

Comment: I expect he knows polarity.

Comment: I don‘t really understand what you mean by „fanout of 10 loads“, and I don‘t really understand what you mean by that the low levels „need“ current. Will it be high if I don‘t pull enough?

Comment: https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/fan-out